# Possible to bind an interface to a type in a specific class?

Tags: binding, ninject

It is possible with Ninject (Most recent version) to bind an interface to a type in a specific class ? By that i mean... lets say i have two classes..

ClassA and ClassB, both have IContext injection in the constructor.. it is possible to say bind type IContext to ContextA for ClassA and IContext to ContextB to ClassB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using named bindings you can also use conditional bindings which requires less code and is more typesafe:

```
Bind<IContext>().To<ContextA>().WhenInjectedInto<SomeClassThatNeedsAContext>();
Bind<IContext>().To<ContextB>().WhenInjectedInto<SomeOtherClassThatNeedsBContext>();
```

Comment: Simplest ! +1 This is a better answer i think. Require less code.

Comment: @Brook don't worry you had an excellent answer aswell. :) There actually 3 reasons i choosen this answer. 1- Its more intuitive. 2- I personnally try to avoid magic string. 3- Less code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use named bindings.

```
kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<ContextA>().Named("A");
kernel.Bind<IContext>().To<ContextB>().Named("B");

kernel.Bind<SomeClassThatNeedsContext>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("context",ninjectContext=>ninjectContext.Get<IContext>("A"));
kernel.Bind<SomeOtherClassThatNeedsContext>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("context",ninjectContext=>ninjectContext.Get<IContext>("B"));
```

Another way might be to just use the "WithConstructorArgument" by itself

```
kernel.Bind<SomeClassThatNeedsAContext>().ToSelf().WithConstructorArgument("context",ninjectContext=>ninjectContext.Get<ContextA>());
```

Just to avoid confusion, Ninject has the concept of a context as well, do not confuse that with your provided sample IContext etc.

One thing I have found from experience is that often if I find myself doing this, there is a flaw in my interface or class design somewhere.  Maybe you really need two different interfaces?

Comment: Nah..  IContext in my case represent a context to access a specific database. It simply that i am using another database for a specific class in my project so i have to inject an other context to the repository of it. That why i can't have 2 interface plus it doesnt make sense to me to have 2 interfaces. The base repository is taking an IContext. The idea is to be able to pass a context to the main repository which contains the connectionstring (taken from the config). This enable me to have multiple databases for one project.